# Why don't my settings persist after a reboot in Mac OS X 10.7.4?

Tags: mac, osx-lion

Every time I change my desktop background or the default application to open a file, OS X does it well. But when I restart, the changes are not saved.

Does anybody know whats happening?

Answer (score 0):

Let's investigate the wallpaper issue as its easier problem to investigate and will most likely solve the other problem.

You might have a permissions problem. Take a look at:

```
ls -la ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist
```

Mine looks like this

```
-rw------- 1 cmdcentral staff 2603 Feb  5 16:39 Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist
```

If you open this file

```
nano ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist
```

You will find your wallpaper's location in there. I found mine in there somewhere, looking like this:

`......^@^@^@_^P9/Users/cmdcentral/Pictures/1359637970_phpcode_287392.jpeg"G@Z~/PicturesUNeverO^P @^@^@^@^@ @^C^`

See what your permissions are and compare them, also check if the location of your wallpaper is changing after you save it in System Preferences. Please also take a look if it is the same before you shutdown and after you start up.

If your permissions seem correct but the problem persists we can take it to step two.

Comment: mine looks like this: -rw-r--r--+ 1 me staff 1585 Mar 25 2012 /Users/me/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plis AND in nano looks like this (even after restarting): /Users/me/Pictures/Ferrari-FF_2012_1600x1200_wallpaper_07a‌​utomotiveface.com_photo.jpg

Comment: It does seem like you have permission problems, giving more permissions than needed can also cause problems. Please do

    chmod -R 700 ~/Library/Preferences
    chown -R me:staff ~/Library/Preferences

I have a feeling this might help. Let me know!

Comment: Everything got fixed up, but Chrome "Didn't shotdown properly"

Comment: So it's all working but chrome has that issues now?

Comment: Yes, some apps act weird, for example, 'recent open documents' appear always the same documents.

Comment: Go to Disk Utility.app and select your drive, then click Repair Disk Permissions. Hopefully this will be the last step. Good luck.

Comment: It didn't work. Do you think it is google chrome's bug? Maybe reinstalling google chrome.

Comment: If only Chrome is broken, that might be a good idea. Make sure to remove all the files chrome installed, not just the .app file.